# React: how to generate one pdf with one component multiplied three times with different props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the react component that is wrapping other react components. I want to make pdf of it. The problem is that one of wrapped component is a bar chart - at the view is only one but in generated pdf I want to have this chart printed three times but with different data sets.

To clarify things here is the screenshot of this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSkZp.png)

When I change connections/systems/calls dataset for chart is changing and 'Details tile' is rerendering.

Is possible to achive this by using some react library or I have to do this different way?

Comment: you want to show only one bar chart but in pdf, show 3 bar charts?

Comment: The screenshot is representing the view page. In PDF I need to have all this tiles that You can see at the screenshot but the difference is that I must have three bar charts for three different props, not one.

Comment: sounds like you need to make a loop that accepts different props on each iteration, if you want more help I will need to see the code

Comment: But do I need some library like for example React-pdf?